# switch state is not stable in listview when scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I'am new to android and i use sample for my listview. because of that i can't change the code. i have one switch button in each item of my Listview. when i scroll the Listview switches change state randomly. how can i make switch state stable?

my listview class adapter:

```
public class MyCustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
LIGHTS calling_activity; 
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

public MyCustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
    this.calling_activity = (LIGHTS) context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter,parent,false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper._ID)));
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.KEYCODE)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.TITLE)));
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.NAME)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.DESC)));

    ImageView option = view.findViewById(R.id.itemoption);

    Switch thisswitch = view.findViewById(R.id.onoff);
    thisswitch.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper._ID)));
    thisswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {    calling_activity.myOnCheckedChangedHandler((String)buttonView.getTag(),isChecked);
        }
    });
    option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView itemID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            TextView itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.KEYCODE);
            TextView itemDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NAME);

            String myId = itemID.getText().toString();
            String myTitle = itemTitle.getText().toString();
            String myDesc = itemDesc.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(calling_activity, ModifyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Id", myId);
            intent.putExtra("Title", myTitle);
            intent.putExtra("Desc", myDesc);
            calling_activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

and in my Lights activity :

```
@Override
public void myOnCheckedChangedHandler(String id, boolean check_status) {
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "You changed the status for the row with an id of " + id +
                    " the status is now " + new Boolean(check_status).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.DESC));

    if(new Boolean(check_status).toString().equals("true")){
        Toast.makeText(this,name +" is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please manage through if/else case inside bindView at adapter, You need to check the switch condition like below :

```
// set the code into bind
if(switchCondition1 == 1)
{
 //set the code as per condition wise 
}else{
//
}
```

After change the state you also need to change the state into your list item and  use notifydatasetChanged() method to refresh the list items.